# Exercise 6.1.1 in Qing Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the exercise in the title, which should be an alternative way to construct the sheaf of differentials:

" Let $B$ be an $A$-module. Let $\rho$: $B \otimes_A B$ $\longrightarrow$ $B$ be the 'diagonal' homomorphism $\rho(b_1 \otimes b_2)=b_1b_2$. Let $I=Ker(\rho)$. We can consider $B \otimes_A B$ as a $B$-module. Let $d$: $B$ $\longrightarrow$ $I/I^2$ be defined by $d(b)=b \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b$.

(a) Show that d is an $A$-derivation.

(b) Show that the $B$-module $I/I^2$ endowed with the $A$-derivation  $d$ verifies the universal property of the module of differentials of $B$ over $A$.

(c) Let $f$: $X$ $\longrightarrow$ $Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $\Delta$: $X$ $\longrightarrow$ $X \times_Y X$ be the diagonal morphism. Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the kernel of $\Delta^\text{#}$: $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\Delta_∗$ $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Show that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ $\simeq$ $\Delta$*$(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)$ "

(a):

For what concerns this point, after observing that $d(a)=0$ with $a \in A$, I just verified that $d$ follows Leibnitz rule:

$d(b_1 b_2)=b_1 b_2 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b_1 b_2 = (b_1 b_2 \otimes 1 - b_1 \otimes b_2) + (b_1 \otimes b_2 - 1 \otimes b_1 b_2)$

then just note that

$(b_1 b_2 \otimes 1 - b_1 \otimes b_2) - (1 \otimes b_1 b_2 - b_2 \otimes b_1) = (b_2 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b_2)(b_1 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b_1) \in I^2$

so conclude that $d(b_1 b_2) = b_1d(b_2) + b_2d(b_1)$

(b):

Here I'm already stuck: I tried in vain, making a few attempts, to find the homomorphism $\Phi$ that satisfies the universal property.

(c):

I don't know if solving point (b) gives hints on how to solve this point, but up to now I have no Idea of how to proceed

Comment: See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About point (b) I proved that $I/I^2$ satisfies the universal property of $\Omega_{B/A}$:

I need to define a homomorphism $\Phi$: $I/I^2$ $\longrightarrow$ $M$ for every $M$ B-module and $d':B \longrightarrow M$ A-derivation and then prove the uniqueness of $\Phi$

$\Phi\big( \big[ \displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} c_i b_i \otimes c_i \big] \big) := \displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} d'(b_i)c_i $ which is a homomorphism and satisfies $\Phi \circ d = d'$ and is well defined as:

$[\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} b_i \otimes c_i] = [\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} \tilde{b}_i \otimes \tilde{c}_i]$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} \tilde{b}_i \otimes \tilde{c}_i = \displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} b_i \otimes c_i + (\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} h_i \otimes e_i)(\displaystyle \sum_{j \in I}f_j \otimes g_j)$ with $h_ie_i = f_jg_j = 0$

But $\Phi([\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} h_i \otimes e_i)(\displaystyle \sum_{j \in I}f_j \otimes g_j]) = 0$ indeed:

$\Phi([\displaystyle \sum_{i \in I} h_i \otimes e_i)(\displaystyle \sum_{j \in I}f_j \otimes g_j]) = \displaystyle \sum_{i,j} \Phi([h_if_j\otimes e_i g_j])$

But $\forall i,j$ $\Phi([h_if_j\otimes e_i g_j])= e_ig_jd'(h_if_j)=0$ where the last equality follows very easily by Leibinitz.

So we just need to prove the uniqueness of $\Phi$ but this follows from the fact that it is the inverse homomorphism of $\tilde{\Phi}: \Omega_{B/A}\longrightarrow I/I^2$ which sends $b_1d_{B/A}b_2 \longrightarrow [b_2 \otimes b_1 - 1 \otimes b_1b_2]$.

So we proved that $\Omega_{B/A}$ and $I/I^2$ are isomorphic.

Point (c): [Point c of exercise 6.1.1 in Qing Liu's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821324/point-c-of-exercise-6-1-1-in-qing-lius-book)

Comment: I haven't looked at Liu's book. The point of (c) is supposed to be that it follows from (b) and some general nonsense about local properties. Has he discussed any of these principles for giving scheme theoretic proofs?

Comment: @A. Thomas Yerger I’ve just edited my answer using what I found.