# Point c of exercise 6.1.1 in Qing Liu's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I’m trying to solve the last point of the exercise in the title. I already asked a question about the whole exercise here [Exercise 6.1.1 in Qing Liu's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4818857/1013808) but I decided to post this specific point alone because I think it is more specifically an algebraic geometry question: I'll possibly update the answer on the original question.

I report the text of the exercise for completness:

" Let $B$ be an $A$-module. Let $\rho$: $B \otimes_A B$ $\longrightarrow$ $B$ be the 'diagonal' homomorphism $\rho(b_1 \otimes b_2)=b_1b_2$. Let $I=Ker(\rho)$. We can consider $B \otimes_A B$ as a $B$-module. Let $d$: $B$ $\longrightarrow$ $I/I^2$ be defined by $d(b)=b \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes b$.
(a) Show that d is an $A$-derivation. (b) Show that the $B$-module $I/I^2$ endowed with the $A$-derivation $d$ verifies the universal property of the module of differentials of $B$ over $A$.

(c) Let $f$: $X$ $\longrightarrow$ $Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $\Delta$: $X$ $\longrightarrow$ $X \times_Y X$ be the diagonal morphism. Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote the kernel of $\Delta^\text{#}$: $\mathcal{O}_{X \times_Y X}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\Delta_∗$ $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Show that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ $\simeq$ $\Delta$*$(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)$ "

I should have solved (a) and (b) as can be found at the link. About the last point, here is my attempt:

(c):

In (b) one ends up showing that $\Omega_{B/A} \simeq I/I^2$. Now, let $V=Spec(A) \subset Y$ and $U = Spec(B) \subset X$ with $f(U) \subset V$.

The module $\Omega_{A/B}$ and the sheaf $\Omega_{U/V}$ are well defined.

We have $U \times_V U = Spec(B\otimes_A B) \subset X \times_Y X$ affine and open (the equality is not completely clear/justified to me: is it correct?).

By (b) we have $\Omega_{B/A} \simeq I/I^2$ and so: $\Omega_{U/V} = (\Omega_{B/A})\tilde{} \simeq (I/I^2)\tilde{}$

I hope it is correct but in that case I still don’t know how to formally conclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the equality $U \times_V U= \operatorname{Spec}(B \otimes_A B)$ is correct.

Indeed, for any scheme $S$, $(U \times_V U)(S)$ is the set of couples of maps $S \rightarrow U$ that coincide when composed with $U \rightarrow V$. Because $U,V$ are affine, this set identifies with the set of couples of maps $B \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(S)$ that coincide when precomposed with $A \rightarrow B$.

In other words, the two schemes have isomorphic functors of points, so are isomorphic.

The rest of your argument is, however, incomplete for a subtler reason.

Consider the two modules $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. They are, of course, not isomorphic. Yet, if you restrict them to any affine open subset (or at least an affine cover), they become so! Your reasoning would prove them isomorphic – so something is missing.

The issue is that you considered only *local* isomorphisms, without any consideration as to whether they could glue to a global isomorphism. So this is how I would solve the problem:

1. consider $U,V$ as above: then the set of such $U$ forms an open cover of $X$, and we have the universal derivation $d_{U,V}: (\Omega_{X/Y})_{|U} \rightarrow (\Delta^{\ast}\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)_{|U}$, which is, by your argument, an isomorphism.
2. $d_{U,V}$ does not depend on the choice of $V$, and we can write it $d_U$. This is abstract nonsense.
3. if $(U,V),(U’,V’)$ are as in 1), and $W \subset U \cap U’$ is affine, then $(d_{U})_{|W}$ and $(d_{U’})_{|W}$ agree, because they are both equal to $d_W$.
4. *Therefore*, the $d_U$ glue to a module homomorphism $\Omega_{X/Y} \rightarrow \Delta^{\ast}\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$, which is locally an isomorphism hence an isomorphism.